# Excel, IFs and Dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

I have a household budget, it is split into fixed and variable expenses. I would like to include the fixed expenses only during/after the month they are incurred.

Not a problem using the following lovely formula (using January as an example):

```
=IF((MONTH(TODAY()))>=1,Jan!A15,0)
```

[Where A15 = my fixed costs for the month].

But, the problem is that if I now go back and look at my 2014 budget all the fixed expenses have gone back to zero, as we’re now in January (or later) again.

What I need to do is tell the formula, that IF it’s later than Jan 2015 (or any given year) then use A15 otherwise 0, but I don’t know how to do it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Don't post your question in multiple places, please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320221/if-statements-date-and-excel/28320614#28320614

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
=IF((TODAY()>DATE(2015,1,31)),Jan!A15,0)
```

After all, if its later than Jan, its later than 31 January 2015

Comment: Thanks - This solved the problem. It's been upsetting me for a very long time.

Comment: @DavidHenson  You are quite welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but maybe:

```
=IF(AND(YEAR(TODAY())>2014,MONTH(TODAY())>=1),Jan!A15,0)
```

Comment: You're not sure?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be for every year, it would be nice to not have to know which are leap years. If you use `0` for the day in the `DATE` function, it uses the last day of the previous month. You can even use a month 13 and Excel treats it as January of the next year.

```
=IF(TODAY()>DATE(2015,2,0),Jan!A15,0)
=IF(TODAY()>DATE(2015,3,0),Feb!A15,0)
=IF(TODAY()>DATE(2015,4,0),Mar!A15,0)
...
=IF(TODAY()>DATE(2015,13,0),Dec!A15,0)
```

Additionally, it'd be nice if you didn't have to hard-code the year values. I don't know how your sheet is setup, but, for an example, let's assume that column B has some date in January 2015. In that case, you can use

```
=IF(TODAY()>DATE(YEAR(Jan!B15),MONTH(Jan!B15)+1,0),Jan!A15,0)
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks that's taking things to the next level - I might give it a try.